# Compact function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider an operarator $A: D(A) \subset X \to X$ generating an analytic semigroup $e^{At}$ of negative type and define as usual (for example see  [Pazy]) the negative powers $(-A)^\theta$ for $0< \theta < 1$.

Consider the following set

$$K_M=\{u \in C([0,T];H) : |u|_{C^\beta([0,T];H)}+ \sup_{t\leq T} |u(t)|_{D(-A)^\theta} \leq M\}$$
Then why is it compact by Ascoli Arzelà?

Comment: I don't think that's true. For example, if $A=-\mathrm{id}$, then $K_M$ contains all constant functions for which the constant has norm $\leq M/2$. This set is homeomorphic to the unit ball in $H$, hence not compact (unless $H$ is finite-dimensional).

Comment: I think this set is compact if and only if the embedding $D((-A)^\theta)\hookrightarrow H$ is compact.

Comment: The condition $D -A^\theta$ Compactly embedded into H is it true for A=-laplacian right?

Comment: That depends on the domain. Not for $H=L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, but it is true for $H=L^2(\Omega)$ with a bounded domain $\Omega$.

Comment: Where can I find some references on these embeddings?

Comment: I think Brezis' book on Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations could be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p\colon H\to [0,\infty]$ be lower semicontinuous. For $M>0$ the set
$$
K=\{u\in C([0,T];H):\lvert u\rvert_{C^\beta([0,T];H)}+\sup_{t\leq T}p(u(t))\leq M\}
$$
is compact if and only if $\{\xi\in H\mid p(\xi)\leq M\}$ is compact:

By the Arzela-Ascoli theorem the set $K$ is compact if and only if it is closed, equicontinuous and for every $t\in [0,T]$ the set $\{u(t): u\in K\}$ is compact. The set $K$ is closed because $u\mapsto \lvert u\rvert_{C^\beta([0,T];H)}+\sup_{t\leq T}p(u(t))$ is lower semicontinuous and equicontinuous because of the bound on the Hölder seminorm. Finally, $\{u(t):u\in K\}=\{\xi\in H\mid p(\xi)\leq M\}$. On the one hand, if $u\in K$, then $p(u(t))\leq M$ by definition. On the other hand, if $\xi\in H$ with $p(\xi)\leq M$, then the constant function $s\mapsto \xi$ belongs to $K$.

Now in the specific case when $p(\xi)=(\lVert \xi\rVert^2+\lVert A\xi\rVert^2)^{1/2}$ for some closed operator $A$ (and $p(\xi)=\infty$ if $\xi\notin D(A)$) this means that $K$ is compact if and only if the embedding $(D(A),\lVert\cdot\rVert_A)\hookrightarrow H$ is compact if and only if $(1+A^\ast A)^{-1}$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks you very Much !